# How to upload to file cabinet similar with UI's "Attach from Web" using suitescript?

Tags: netsuite

Using an image type custom field in netsuite, users can add a new file to file cabinet with the following settings in UI:
Attach from = "Web"
URL = "file's url"

Can we do the same using suite script?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a sample code using a suitelet.

```
            if(request.getMethod() == 'GET') {
                var form = nlapiCreateForm('Test Upload', false);
                form.addField('custpage_upload_file', 'file', 'Upload', null, null); //Upload Control
                form.addSubmitButton();
                response.writePage(form);
            }
            else {
                var file = request.getFile('custpage_upload_file');
                file.setFolder(-4);
                var id = nlapiSubmitFile(file);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

"Attaching from Web" isn't possible in SuiteScript yet as the nlobjFile object does not support a setURL method. I believe you should file this as an Enhancement ticket to NetSuite support.